Which goods and sevices can effectively be blocked by international sanctions?
Various groups of countries have been imposing economic sanctions on some selected countries for various political reasons (current economic sanctions against Russia by the collective west, US embargo on Cuba, etc..).
However, if there is a third country that is not sanctioned and does not participate in the sanctioning program, trade between the sanctioned country and the sanctioning one could still occur via this/these country/ies (see [Central Asian countries for the current sanctions on Russia][1]).  
I am curious to know which types of goods/services can effectively escape this type of loophole. I imagine that some mechanisms must be in place to enforce sanctions on particular sensitive goods (e.g., military equipment, airplanes, some software solutions), but I am not sure how these mechanism works and how effective they are.
So my question is: Which goods or services can be effectively barred from trade between sanctioned and sanctioning countries in the current world economy? 
Note: I am not saying that sanctions are not effective; I imagine that going through a third country increases the trading costs quite considerably.
 [1]: https://www.ebrd.com/news/2023/ebrd-analyses-trade-flows-between-russia-caucasus-and-central-asia.html

I believe it's a better match for Economics.SE.

What do you consider effectively banned? To ban something 100% is of course virtually impossible, bans typically just restrict availability and then it’s matter of a degree.

@1muflon1 effectively blocked like 99% of the trade is stopped.
